# What are the consequences of having almost duplicate target rules in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

I have inherited a problematic Makefile.am that has been causing build issues. In this makefile, there are a couple instances where there are almost duplicate target rules. They are almost duplicate because the second one has one or two extra prerequisites. Here is an example:

```
target1 target2: prereq1 prereq2 
        ACTION

target1 target2: prereq1 prereq2 prereq3
        ACTION
```

The action is identical, and target1 and target2 are identical. What is the consequence of this? Will both rules be executed?

To extend this question a bit, if prereq3 was auto generated during the make process, how would this play out? If make is run in parallel, could this cause big issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The action is identical, and target1 and target2 are identical. What
>   is the consequence of this? Will both rules be executed?

The consequence is that the makefiles generated based on this `Makefile.am`, which will include both rules verbatim, will fail to conform to the POSIX specifications for makefiles.  POSIX forbids that more than one target rule provide a recipe for any given target.

If you happen to use GNU `make` to build, then instead of rejecting the makefile outright, it will use the last-given recipe for each target; all other target rules for each target will be treated as prerequisite-only rules, whether they provide a recipe or not.  If you use a different `make` (which the Autotools expressly support), then results may differ.  Relying on implementation-specific behavior such as this is very poor form in Autotools build systems.

Since the recipes are the same, the targets are the same, and the prerequisite list of the earlier rule is a subset of the prerequisite list of the later rule, I see no reason whatever to retain the earlier rule.  Just delete it wholesale.  No behavior will change under GNU `make`, and you will not have to worry about the behavior of other `make`s differing on account of this issue.

That does presume, however, that there are no *other* target rules for either `target1` or `target2`. If the last-appearing rule for `target2` that provides a recipe is a different one than the last-appearing rule for `target1` that provides a recipe, then two recipes will run: one to generate `target1` (maybe with a side effect of also generating `target2`), and the other to generate `target2` (maybe with a side effect of also generating `target1`).  The relative order of those is unspecified, and the result might be inconsistent.

You should also read [the Automake manual's comments on tools and rules that generate multiple targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Multiple-Outputs.html#Multiple-Outputs).

> To extend this question a bit, if prereq3 was auto generated during the make process, how would this play out?

No differently than already described, at least for GNU `make`.  It is possible that the construction you describe was motivated by a misunderstanding of this issue, or perhaps that it targeted the implementation-specific behavior of some other `make` implementation than `GNU`'s, but if, currently, the software builds correctly with GNU `make` then removing the first rule just converts the resulting makefile to a POSIX-conforming one (in this respect), with no reason to expect any change in behavior.

There may be nuances and alternative solutions associated with the specifics of your situation, but all of the above comments apply regardless of any such details.

> If make is run in parallel, could this cause big issues?

Rule duplication of the form you describe has no particular interaction with parallel `make`.  However, you will likely run into issues with parallel make if you do not express the full dependencies of each target, and especially the dependencies on other built targets.  But note that you don't generally need to express dependencies on C or C++ header files, even built ones, because Automake-generated makefiles include code for detecting and tracking these automatically.

BUT, if you have other target rules that provide recipes for one or both targets, as mentioned above, then yes, that will be an issue for parallel `make`.  Do yourself a favor, and ensure that no target has a recipe specified by more than one target rule.

Also, although the rule duplication might not be an issue for parallel `make`, if one run of the recipe generates both targets, then *that* might create issues for parallel `make`.  Refer to the Automake manual, linked above, for more commentary on that point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive reply. I have spent quite a bit of time with the info you gave me trying to figure out which rules should be removed. In doing so I have been removing certain rules and trying a build. The first thing I tried was removing all dupes and leaving the second rules intact. I figured since these are the ones being honoured by make, I could take out the others. This was not the case.. Once these rules are taken out the build no longer succeeds. So these rules must be used somehow, correct?

Comment: The second thing I tried was, out of the "dupes" I kept the rules with the most prereqs. This also failed.

Comment: @short-aj, the first strategy you describe sounds consistent with what I have recommended.  If the build no longer worked after that then I'm inclined to think that there are some important details that were not conveyed by the question.  Note also: it may be worthwhile to work with one set of duplicate rules at a time instead of all at once.  This will reduce the scope of the changes and allow you to focus on each situation individually.

Comment: I did fail to mention that all these rules are pattern rules. I'm guessing that would make it so make does not only choose the last one in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using gnu make, the warning indicate that the first rule is ignored. Running `make` with lol execute the ACTION from the 2nd recipe. The ACTION from the first recipe can removed (which will remove the warnings!).

```
make

Makefile:5: warning: overriding recipe for target 'target1'
Makefile:2: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'target1'
Makefile:5: warning: overriding recipe for target 'target2'
Makefile:2: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'target2'
echo "Action2"
Action2
```

Quoting from gnu make manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

> warning: overriding recipe for target `xxx'
>   warning: ignoring old recipe for target`xxx'
>
> GNU make allows only one recipe to be
>   specified per target (except for double-colon rules). If you give a
>   recipe for a target which already has been defined to have one, this
>   warning is issued and the second recipe will overwrite the first. See
>   Multiple Rules for One Target.

Comment: Could you add to your answer with the little makefile you wrote to produce that output?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it as well, thanks for your answer